# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: any for class: myPipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

We are migrating to using pipelines.  We have dozens of builds, so I am trying to create a single pipeline to share amongst the builds.  I have read the blog posts and followed the examples but I can't seem to make this work on our build server.  I updated the plugins today but I get the following error, which makes me think I'm losing global context somewhere because it isn't associating `any` correctly, even though I copied what is in the [docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-declarative-pipelines).

```
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: any for class: myPipeline
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.getProperty(DefaultInvoker.java:39)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at myPipeline.call(/var/jenkins_home/jobs/SpringBootApps-Git/jobs/abc-multibranch/branches/enable-multibranch/builds/17/libs/my-customer-lib/vars/myPipeline.groovy:56)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.call(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:56)
    at myPipeline.call(/var/jenkins_home/jobs/SpringBootApps-Git/jobs/abc-multibranch/branches/enable-multibranch/builds/17/libs/my-customer-lib/vars/myPipeline.groovy:55)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:3)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor516.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

*my-customer-lib/vars/myPipeline.groovy*

```groovy
#!groovy

def call(body) {
    // evaluate the body block, and collect configuration into the object
    def pipelineParams = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = pipelineParams
    body()

    def APP_NAME = 'abc'
    def WEBAPP_LOCATION
    def UI_LOCATION
    def VERSION
    def NAME

    def isMergeRequest = !!env.gitlabMergeRequestLastCommit
    def isDeployed = env.gitlabSourceBranch == "develop" || env.BRANCH_NAME == "develop"

    def handleCheckout = {  ->
      if(isMergeRequest) {
      sh "echo 'Merge request detected. Merging...'"
      checkout changelog: true, poll: true, scm: [
          $class: 'GitSCM',
          branches: [[name: "origin/${env.gitlabSourceBranch}"]],
          doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
          extensions: [
                        [$class: 'PreBuildMerge',
                         options: [
                            fastForwardMode: 'FF',
                            mergeRemote: 'origin',
                            mergeStrategy: 'default',
                            mergeTarget: env.gitlabTargetBranch
                          ]
                        ],
                        [$class: 'PruneStaleBranch'],
                        [$class: 'CleanCheckout']
                      ],
          submoduleCfg: [],
          userRemoteConfigs: [[name: 'origin', url: 'ssh://git@myserver:20022/app/abc.git']]
        ]
      } else {
      sh "echo 'No merge request detected. Checking out current branch'"
      checkout ([
        $class: 'GitSCM',
        branches: scm.branches,
        extensions: [
            [$class: 'PruneStaleBranch'],
            [$class: 'CleanCheckout']
        ],
        userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs
    ])
      }
    }

    pipeline {
        agent any  //ERROR COMES HERE: line 56
        environment {
         // there is likely a better way to make this happen - but the documentation doesn't seem to reflect reality
         // this assumes you have a tool named docker in the jenkins->configureTools->dockerInstalations.  make sure you
         // have the tool from install latest from Docker.io
         PATH = "${tool 'docker'}/bin:$PATH"

        }

          stage('Checkout') {
           steps {
             script {
               handleCheckout()
             }
           }
          }

          stage('Environment') {
           steps {


            script {
             def workspace = pwd()
             WEBAPP_LOCATION = "${workspace}/${APP_NAME}-webapp"
             UI_LOCATION = "${workspace}/${APP_NAME}-ui"

             echo "webapp is at: ${WEBAPP_LOCATION}"
             echo "ui is at: ${UI_LOCATION}"

             VERSION = 'DEV-SNAPSHOT';
             NAME = 'abc';


             // print all environment variables
             sh 'printenv'

             echo "version: ${VERSION}"
             echo "name: ${NAME}"
             echo "path: ${PATH}"
             echo "DOCKER_SERVER: ${DOCKER_SERVER}"
             echo "DOCKER_REGISTRY: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}"
             echo "MERGE REQUEST: ${env.gitlabMergeRequestLastCommit}"
            }

            updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'build', state: 'running'
           }
          }
    }
}
```

*Jenkinsfile*

```groovy
@Library('my-customer-lib') _

myPipeline {
  projectId = 'abc'
}
```